# Conditional importing of components in Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have this issue, I want to import different components on same route.

This works fine

```
import Mycomponent from '@/views/Mycomponent'

{
  name: 'My component name',
  path: somepath,
  component: Mycomponent,
}
```

This  doesn't  work

```
import Mycomponent from '@/views/Mycomponent'
import MycomponentDifferent from '@/views/MycomponentDifferent'

{
  name: 'My component name',
  path: somepath,
  component: () => {
    if(true) {
     console.log(Mycomponent) // You can see in console whole component
     return Mycomponent
    } else {
     return MycomponentDifferent
    }
  }
}
```

and this is also not working

```
import Mycomponent from '@/views/Mycomponent'

{
  name: 'My component name',
  path: somepath,
  component: () => {
    return HomepageView
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it somewhere documented that you can use a function for `component`?
Instead of a function you could use a getter:

```
import Mycomponent from '@/views/Mycomponent'
import MycomponentDifferent from '@/views/MycomponentDifferent'

{
  name: 'My component name',
  path: somepath,
  get component() {
    if(true) {
     console.log(Mycomponent) // You can see in console whole component
     return Mycomponent
    } else {
     return MycomponentDifferent
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But, this way your code will import the two components anyway.

Comment: For this you will have to take a look at [Async Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components)